# Extract all text from \section tag in LaTeX

Tags: python, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup, latex

How do I extract only section text from from the following LaTeX?

> \section{Introduction}
>
> Direct detection techniques,  like those that discovered the prototype
>   T dwarf Gl 229B \citep{Na95,Op99},  have been used for the last 15
>   years to search for brown dwarfs around nearby  stars\footnote{For a
>   review of these companion searches see \citet{Op99}}.   Despite the
>   large samples involved, only two {\it bona fide} brown  dwarf
>   companions have been directly detected,  Gl 229B and the young L-type
>   brown dwarf  G 196-3B \citep{Re98}\footnote{The companion object GD
>   165B \citep{Be89} may also be a brown dwarf, although its status is
>   questionable \citep{Ki99b}.}. Since most of these searches have been
>   confined to a narrow field of view  around the   primary (typically
>   10-60$\arcsec$), widely separated companions\footnote{We adopt an
>   observational definition for ``widely separated'' as angular 
>   separation greater than 100$\arcsec$; see \citet{Fi92}.}  may be
>   missed.  Indeed, both   G 196-3B and  Gl 229B are less than
>   20$\arcsec$ from their primary.  Field surveys, such as the Two Micron
>   All Sky Survey \citep[hereafter 2MASS]{Sk97}, the DEep Near Infrared
>   Survey  \citep[hereafter DENIS]{Ep97},  and the Sloan Digital Sky 
>   Survey \citep[hereafter SDSS]{Yk99}, overcome this limitation. 
>   Indeed,  \citet{Ki00} have recently identified  two  L-type brown
>   dwarf companions at wide separation.
>
> We are currently searching the 2MASS catalogs for field T dwarfs 
>   \citep{Bg98}, brown dwarfs  spectrally identified by CH$*4$ absorption
>   bands  at 1.6 and 2.2 $\micron$ \citep{Ki99a}.   One of our
>   discoveries,   2MASSW J1457150-212148 (hereafter  Gl 570D), has been
>   confirmed as a  widely separated, common proper motion companion  to
>   the  Gl 570ABC system. This system is comprised of a K4V primary and a
>   M1.5V-M3V close  binary \citep{Du88,Mi90,Fo99} at a distance of 
>   5.91$\pm$0.06 pc \citep{Pe97}.  In $\S$2 we describe the selection of this object from the 2MASS database, review subsequent observations, 
>   and establish its common proper motion with  Gl 570ABC. In $\S$3 we
>   estimate L and T$*{eff}$ of  Gl 570D based on its distance and
>   brightness, and make T$_{eff}$ and mass  estimates using the
>   evolutionary models of \citet{Bu97}.

(I'm mainly concerned about removing the tags with `\`, I'm not sure what to do with the `$` tags yet).

I've tried with TexSoup:

```
with open("latex/" + file) as f:
    try:
        soup = TexSoup(f)
        # Parse article body if .tex is a document, defined by /begin{document}
        # Any errors in LaTeX formatting will result in file discard
        if soup.document:
            # If a \section or \subsection tag
            lastChildIsSection = False
            for child in soup.document.contents:
                # If last child was \section or \subsection and current child is text,
                if lastChildIsSection and isinstance(child, str):
                    # Get text
                    print(child)

                # Check if \section or \subsection
                if type(child).__name__ == 'TexNode' and (child.name == 'section' or child.name == 'subsection'):
                    lastChildIsSection = True
                else:
                    lastChildIsSection = False
```

This looks for \section tags and then gets the next child, which is a str representing some text. Unfortunately this isn't all of the text in the section, since the text ends as soon as the next tag appears, in this case a `\cite` tag.

How can I extract all of the text from the section? I'm open to any approach, including regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Tex2py, built off of TexSoup, will do the job for you https://github.com/alvinwan/tex2py. Say we have the following:

- We only want the text (not the `\section{...}`, `\subsection{...}`). However, this includes bulleted lists, bolded words, citations etc.
- Note that there are two `\section`s. Say we only want text from the first one. (we can fetch all of them, but adding this constraint just to make it harder)

Say the following is saved in a variable called `data`

```
\section{Chikin Tales}

\subsection{Chikin Fly}

Chickens don't fly. They do only the following:

\begin{itemize}
\item waddle
\item plop
\end{itemize}

\section{Chikin Scream}

\subsection{Plopping}

Plopping involves three steps:
```

We can process it using the following.

```
>>> toc = tex2py(data)
>>> print([text for text in toc.section.subsection.descendants])
["\n\nChickens don't fly. They do only the following:\n\n", \begin{itemize}

\item waddle
\item plop\end{itemize}]
```

Here, `toc.section` grabs the first section, but we can use `toc.sections` to grab all sections. Admittedly, whitespace isn't preserved at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in one go, so I would first extract **everything** belonging to a section with a regex like `\\section{[\w\s]*}(.*)\\section{` (*this may need to be improved if more than word-characters or whitespace could appear in a section-title).
And then I would replace all tags in that result with an exmpty string. I'm not sure about TeX-Syntax and rx in Python, but something along the lines of `\\\w*{.*}` (non-greedy mode) might do it.
Sorry, not a complete solution, I'm too unfamiliary with both TeX and Python, but I hope you'll get some ideas ;-)